# is it support the jpeg picture deal with GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES mode likes deal with video

Tags: cobalt

For saving memory and improving performance，I want to use a special format texture to deal with jpeg picture. The format handles by GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES but process is same to GL_TEXTURE_2D (only different from glBindTexture and shader program texture declaration)
  I have done it in egl hardware mode('rasterizer_type': 'direct-gles'). But have problems when I use skia hardware mode ('rasterizer_type': 'hardware'), I found skia hardware mode don`t support it directly  and will call render_image_fallback_function_ (HardwareRasterizer::Impl::RenderTextureEGL) to deal with it likes 360 video. I found the result for display is very different from it show in egl hardware mode, It seems that the way only use to deal with 360 video. Is there a way to possible I let skia hardware mode support the special format directly or I only add a new way in TexturedMeshRenderer to deal with picture to distinguish 360 video.

Comment: This question only to communicate with this ideal`s feasibility, because I don`t  know skia clearly now, need some one who have experience give me some suggestions don`t beg to finally result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cobalt/Starboard supports letting the platform define custom (possibly accelerated) image decode functionality in starboard/image.h, are you using this to set GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, or are you modifying common Cobalt code?

If you are modifying Cobalt code, you may want to search through https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/renderer/rasterizer/skia/hardware_image.cc for references to "GL_TEXTURE_2D" and make sure that they still make sense after your changes.  In particular, you may need to adjust HardwareFrontendImage::CanRenderInSkia().

Comment: thx your reply, I am modifying some common Cobalt code. when I do it in egl mode. For example add  member variable and functions in `class HardwareFrontendImage` to sign the image whether generate by my jpeg piture with GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES format. And add `class ShaderFragmentColorTexcoordMyformat : public ShaderBase` to define my special  Fragment shader.  And add judgement in function Visit witch in https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/renderer/rasterizer/egl/render_tree_node_visitor.cc file. It can work now. But it more complex on skia hardware mode.